# Javascript regex to extract year from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, timestamp

I'm trying to extract the year from a timestamp using regex, but I'm not very good at it, so my code isn't returning what expected.

that's the string: '**Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)**'

I need to extract '2012' here's my code:

```
var scrollDate = tl.getBand(0).getCenterVisibleDate(); // my timestamp

// regex function
function extractNumbers(str) {
     var m = /(^|\s)(\d{4})(\s|$)/.exec(str);
     return m;
}

// click event
$('.n-left').click(function(){
     alert(extractNumbers(scrollDate));
});
```

The alert box returns this: **2012 , ,2012,**

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use a regex for this, it's the wrong tool for the job, use James Kleeh's approach of just letting Date parse the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var x = new Date("Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)");

 alert(x.getUTCFullYear());
```

Answer (score 3):

That regular expression uses capture groups. If you look at the return value of `exec()`, you’ll notice it looks something like this:

```
[" 2012 ", " ", "2012", " "]
```

So, you might want to write `extractNumbers()` something like this:

```
function extractNumbers(str) {
     var m = /(^|\s)(\d{4})(\s|$)/.exec(str);
    if (m) {
        return m[2];
    }
}
```

FWIW, you can use non-capturing groups to group parts of the regexp but only capture what you need. A regexp like this:

```
/(?:^|\s)(\d{4})(?:\s|$)/
```

Would return a match array like this:

```
[" 2012 ", "2012"]
```

EDIT: …but [James Kleeh’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321672/javascript-regex-to-extract-year-from-string/12321793#12321793) is like a much nicer option.

Answer (score 0):

First, it works with RegexBuddy (it returns group #1 successfully).

Another regex you might wanna try, which looks simpler to me: `.+?\d\d (\d+)` (then take group #1)